# ODP.net and Oracle Functions versus Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I am unable to find any documentation regarding the ODP.net library in reference to functions versus procedures in Oracle.

Currently I am able to call a Stored Procedure in the following Manner:

```
command.CommandText= "function_name";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

In the above code, command is an OracleCommand object.

There is no CommandType of Function. If I set the CommandType to a Stored Procedure and run it against a function, I get the following error: PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined.

Can somebody tell me if there is a way to call functions instead of procedures, or if they have seen documentation stating that this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to create a stored procedure with an output parameter, or call your function through a select statement, perhaps even against dual.

If your procedure is returning rows, then you have to open a cursor for read.